# Keras CNN Model Typevalue errors when using predict method

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am have a keras model that is supposed to take a `(150, 150, 1)` grayscale image as it's input and output an array of length 8.

Here is my model code:

```py
from tensorflow.python import keras
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same', input_shape=(150,150,1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax")
])
```

When I try to use the `.predict()` method, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KerasCNN.py", line 152, in <module>
    ga.run()
  File "/home/User/Documents/Projects/2022/Keras_CNN/Trial1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygad/pygad.py", line 1192, in run
    self.last_generation_fitness = self.cal_pop_fitness()
  File "/home/User/Documents/Projects/2022/Keras_CNN/Trial1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygad/pygad.py", line 1159, in cal_pop_fitness
    fitness = self.fitness_func(sol, sol_idx)
  File "KerasCNN.py", line 112, in fitness
    prediction = model.predict(g_img)
  File "/home/User/Documents/Projects/2022/Keras_CNN/Trial1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 966, in predict
    return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/User/Documents/Projects/2022/Keras_CNN/Trial1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 1813, in predict
    f, ins, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
  File "/home/User/Documents/Projects/2022/Keras_CNN/Trial1/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 1300, in _predict_loop
    index_array = np.arange(num_samples)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'int'
```

I had an ANN (non-CNN) model running earlier that was working fine. When I did some research I could find anything about this error either.

Here is the code I am using to make the prediction:

```py
img = get_image() # (150, 150, 3)
g_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # (150, 150, 1)
g_img = tf.expand_dim(g_img, axis=0)
g_img = tf.expand_dim(g_img, axis=-1) # (1, 150, 150, 1)
prediction = model.predict(g_img)
```

Here are my version numbers:

tensorflow: `1.5.0`

python: `3.69`

numpy: `1.19.5`

Ubuntu: `18.04`

Let me know if theres any other info I can provide! Thanks!

## Answer

Replacing `tf.expand_dim()` with `np.expand_dim()` fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to run perfectly fine on TF 1.15:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import keras
print(tf.__version__)
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same', input_shape=(150,150,1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax")
])
# Create random image
img = np.zeros([150,150,3], dtype=np.uint8)
img[:,:,0] = np.ones([150,150])*64
img[:,:,1] = np.ones([150,150])*128
img[:,:,2] = np.ones([150,150])*192

g_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
g_img = np.expand_dims(g_img, axis=0)
g_img = np.expand_dims(g_img, axis=-1) # (1, 150, 150, 1)
prediction = model.predict(g_img)
print(prediction.shape)
```

```
1.15.2
(1, 8)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. According to [Keras' Documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/), the Conv2D layer expects the input to have the shape of `(batch_size, X, Y, channels)`. Since my batch size is only one image and my image only has 1 channel, I need to keep both those `tf.expand_dims()` lines. Removing them will result in this error: `ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape(1, 150, 150)`

Comment: What is the shape of `g_img` after running `cv2.cvtColor`? And did you retrain your model after changing the input shape ?

Comment: The shape is `(150, 150)` which is why I have to manually input the channels value too. The model is being trained by a GA, which will determine the correct weights for the CNN.

Comment: With both `tf.expand_dims(g_img, axis=0)` and `tf.expand_dims(g_img, axis=-1)`, I still get the same answer as stated in the question: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Dimension' and 'int'`

Answer (score 0):

in code you wrote, the input shape is (224,256,1) so change it to (150,150,1)
try this:

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same', input_shape=(150,150,1)),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same', data_format='channels_last'),
```

do the math to get the desired output.

Comment: Whoops missed that. However, when I changed the input shape to `(150, 150, 1)` I still got the same error

Comment: can you provide the lines where the error appears:  _(File "KerasCNN.py", line 152, in <module>)_

Comment: In the text of the error I provided, the line that the error occurs is the line which contains `prediction = model.predict(g_img)`

Comment: `File "KerasCNN.py", line 112, in fitness
    prediction = model.predict(g_img)`